# Running powershell script with C# code

Tags: c#, powershell

When I try to run the script with my C# code. I get the following error:

```
  "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression."
```

Would this be my C# code that is wrong

```
        Runspace runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        runSpace.Open();

        RunspaceInvoke runSpaceInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runSpace);
        Pipeline pipeLine = runSpace.CreatePipeline();
        pipeLine.Commands.AddScript(@"D:\NewSites\test-new\ConfigureIIS7.ps1");
        try
        {
            pipeLine.Invoke();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        pipeLine.Stop();

        runSpace.Close();
```

Or should I look for the problem in my powershell script? The shell script works when executed normally.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's generally an error you get from [PowerShell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12326038/powershell-if-then-cannot-call-a-method-on-a-null-valued-expression), not from .NET. My debug your script to see what's null, perhaps you need to load a PSSnapin for your script to work.

Comment: When you run the PS script directly it works because you have proper privileges (probably Admin?). I am guessing your .NET app does not have the same privileges and therefore creating objects that are null, and trying to work with those.

Comment: It was cause of errors in my powershell script that C# stopped executing the script. Now i get "SEHException was unhandled. External component has thrown an exception".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a specialist at all but it seems your error is a POWERSHELL error.

See [This](http://communities.quest.com/docs/DOC-10635) for example.

I think the problem is located into your PowerShell script

Answer (score -1):

You could try:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"D:\NewSites\test-new\ConfigureIIS7.ps1");
```